# React Component Not Displaying Files Fetched from Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, next.js, google-drive-api

I am developing a web application using Next.js and React where I need to display a list of Google Drive documents. I am using the Google Drive API to fetch the documents and then trying to display them in a React component. However, the files are not being displayed in the component as expected.

**Problem:**
The App component is supposed to list all the files retrieved from the Google Drive API. While the API call seems to be successful (I can see the data when I console.log it), the files are not being rendered on the page.

**Relevant Code**

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I have checked for any errors in the browser console but didn't find any relevant error messages.
- I have also tried using different lifecycle methods like useEffect to manage the state.

Can someone help me identify why the files are not being rendered in the React component?
Is there something wrong with the way I am handling the data or rendering it in the component?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You have to share the relevant code to have any chance of help.